# nuxt lifecycle method to catch page load event on page navigation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

i came across this situation where after every navigation i have to fire an event but only when everything is rendered in that component.

for eg. navigation structure -

- route A

  - titleComponent

    - a.1 Component
    - a.2 Component
  - faqComponent
- route B

  - x Component
- route C

  - y Component

in this case suppose if route A is rending so i want to fire an event only when all the components inside route A rendered. is there any way we can keep track or something ?

Comment: have you tried mounted with `document.onreadystatechange` ?

Comment: not working! @Evan